# PHP->sql UPDATE row with data from 2 other rows merged together within the same table

Tags: php, mysql, database, field

Table = location
Fields = address, street, suburb

address fields are initially empty, street and suburb are populated. I have tried to update the address field with the street and suburb data but its not working. only allows me to update with one field. With the code below the address field would be updated with 0's... But if i remove one of the variables from the update then it will update correctly with just either the street or suburb.

The reason why im doing this is because the way the data is given to me is in that format and would take too long for me to manually do it.

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $street=$row['street'];
        $suburb=$row['suburb'];

        $mysqli->query("UPDATE address SET address = $street+$suburb");
        echo($street);
}
}
```

Comment: Notice: you have an extra closing bracket at the end of your exemple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to fetch results to PHP and then run an `UPDATE` for every row. It seems you are now sending one `SELECT` and **numerous** (thousands or millions, depends on the size of your table) of `UPDATE` statements to the database.

You can update the whole table (all rows!) with **one** `UPDATE` statement:

```
"UPDATE location SET address = CONCAT(street, ' ', suburb) ;"
```

If (later on) some of your rows have already data in the `address` column, you can update only rows with empty address:

```
"UPDATE location
 SET address = CONCAT(street, ' ', suburb) 
 WHERE address = ''
    OR address IS NULL ;"
```

---

You should also check that the size of `address` field is bigger or at least equal to the maximum of `CHAR_LENGTH(street) + CHAR_LENGTH(suburb) + 1`

Comment: Top one doesnt work, haven't tried bottom one as it wont be required.

Comment: @user829206: what error do you get? Is your table named `location` or `address` ?

Comment: Your description says `location`, your code says `UPDATE address`.

Comment: my table is called location... the code i pasted was a previous db i was using but i made a new one to start fresh called location so don't mind that.

Comment: actually it works! i had a mistake in my query SELECT FROM. was using the old table ahha. Should i have your code in the while loop? wouldn't that still execute as many times as there is rows.

Comment: No, you don't put this in a while loop. You run it once and the database updates all rows.

Comment: awesome thanks mate! This also solves my problem with the ' in O'connor.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to put a WHERE clause in your UPDATE query, unless you want your whole table to have the same adress column. Try this

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $street=$row['street'];
        $suburb=$row['suburb'];
        $address=$street." ".$suburb;
        $id=$row['id'];

        $mysqli->query("UPDATE address SET address = `".address."` WHERE id=".$id);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $street=$row['street'];
        $suburb=$row['suburb'];
    $address = $street.$suburb;

        $mysqli->query("UPDATE address SET address = '$address'");
        echo($street);
}
}
```

Comment: `+` is not a concatenation operator in php

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 $mysqli->query("UPDATE address SET address ='". $street." ".$suburb."' WHERE street = '$street' AND subrub = '$subrub'");
```

`+` is not a concatenation operator in php. So try using `.`

Also, if you dont have the `WHERE` clause, then all the rows will get updated!!!

Comment: This works but it updates all the fields with the last row of data from suburb and street fields.

Comment: see the edit. There was the problem in the query you first posted. There was no `WHERE` clause

Comment: thank you! that works. is it possible to update with a space in between the street and suburb? because right now it comes out as "TEST ROADMANCHESTER"

Comment: hey balvanish. i have ran into a problem... one of the suburbs is called O'connor. It doesnt update the address field i think because of the '. anyway to fix that?

Comment: You need to escape the input before you store it into the database. you can use `htmlspecialchars()`, `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape special chars in PHP